# Modifying table view cell data from inside table view cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

**Background:** Inside my **UITableViewCell** I have a button. This button stores a state of the table view cell. If the button is clicked, it turns red. If it is clicked again it turns gray.

**The problem:** I click the button and it turns red. When I scroll down and back up, it returns to its default state (gray).

Code example (this is inside my custom table view cell -- it is called when favoriteButton is clicked):

```
func likeThisPost() {
    print("like this post")
    let networking = Networking()
    if (favoriteButton.tintColor == Color.red)
    {
        print("unlike this post")
        favoriteButton.tintColor = Color.lightGray
        numLikes = numLikes! - 1
        likesLabel.text = "\(numLikes!)"
    }
    else {
        print("like this post")
        favoriteButton.tintColor = Color.red
        numLikes = numLikes! + 1
        likesLabel.text = "\(numLikes!)"
    }
}
```

Where should I be changing the button color and store the state if not in the table view cell itself?

Comment: You can have a flag in you cell subclass and set it when its favourite , and depending upon this flag you can change this button's color in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 1):

AS we all know the issue is when you scroll up or down, your UITableViewCell will be reloaded and it set state which you give default.

**Solution**

best place to put **status**  is inside array of your tableview datasource

add key inside array like isStatusLiked:Bool  and on based on that condition change button color in uitableViewCell class method

like

```
var isstatusLiked: Bool = false{
        didSet{
            likeButton.tintColor = .darkGray
            if(isLiked)
            {
                likeButton.tintColor = .red
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` reuses `UITableViewCell` objects. When you scroll a cell off the screen, `UITableView` is probably re-using that cell object.

Store your grey/red state outside of the cells (in the ViewController maybe, or somewhere else), and restore the state inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you scroll up or down, your UITableViewCell will be reloaded and it set state which you give.

**Solutions:** You can keep monitor array and need to changed value according to your cell's state. In CellForRow, you need to set the state for the particular cell as per array state.

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll down and back up again, UITabelViewDataSource method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called. Then your cell takes the default state that is specified in that method. Hence you should maintain a boolean, lets say statusLiked, in your main view controller and on that basis assign the color in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: